# Is API for CSRF token safe?

Tags: api, security, csrf, csrf-token

Is it safe to build an API to provide CSRF one-time use token to avoid CSRF attack? Will this open a new vulnerability?
I have one more doubt regarding the traditional approach of including CSRF. I wonder that providing the csrf token in the form can be scraped and attack may be implemented by the attacker. Please correct me if my thought process in incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to understand how a CSRF attack looks like. Someone can send you a link to http://malicious.com/whatever.html. You open this site and there will be an invisible form, that will send a POST request to http://example.com/account/1/delete. You will be logged into example.com on some other tab, so assuming the session is handled via a cookie, the cookie gets automatically attached and you execute a request you never intended to and are even unaware of.

We can mitigate the CSRF issue via different means, on of the being anti-CSRF tokens. The idea is that there is some kind of secret malicious.com will be unaware of and that can not easily be guessed. Please note, that in the CSRF scenario your means of attack are making people open some link. You have no access to the content of what they are seeing. You just send them a link and expect some requested to be executed with their access rights.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. However, If I were to attack on a request that uses ant-CSRF token, cannot I just scrape the token from its place and then produce the attack?

Comment: Where do you want to scrape the token from? The token is a client side secret usually generated once per user session. Every single user will have a different one. And they will get rotated with every session. If implemented correctly, there will be no place to scrape the values from.

Comment: For instace, there is a very popular social media which has a change username form. The form contains a hidden input field having the anti-CSRF token. 
If I try the attack without the token then it will fail but if I code in such a way that first the token from the form is scraped and then the attack is made with the token, then aren't there chances that I will succeed?

Comment: If you guess the anti-CSRF token correctly, then you will succeed. The whole trick is that the token is a secret and that it is different for every user, every session. Try to guess a 128 bit random number. I wish you luck.